# How do I edit an embed field with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I edit an embed field with discord.js?

```
    execute(client, connection, message, args) {
    message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Poll", client, false)
        .setTitle('test')
        .addField(`0`)
    ).then(embedMessage => {
        embedMessage.react(`✅`)
        embedMessage.react(`❎`)
    })

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (user.id === client.user.id) return // if reaction is == bot return
        if (reaction.emoji.name == '✅') message.channel.send(reaction.count)

        embed.editfield("hi")

    })
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `client.on('messageReactionAdd')` fires for all reactions, and doesn't stop, it keeps firing until you stop the bot, so you need to use a [Reaction Collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) and to edit embed, you need to change the embeds field and edit the message itself.

```
execute(client, connection, message, args) {
message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Poll", client, false)
    .setTitle('test')
    .addField(`0`)
).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.react(`✅`)
    embedMessage.react(`❎`)
    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.bot!; //Ignores bot reactions
    collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter,{time:15000)) //The time parameter (in milliseconds) specified for how much time the reactionCollector collects reactions
    collector.on('collect',(reaction,user)=>{ //When a reaction is collected
         const embed = embedMessage.embeds[0] // Get the embed that you want to edit.
         embed.fields[0] = {name : 'The name of the new field' , value : 'Value of new field'}
         await embedMessage.edit(embed)
         })
    collector.on('end',()=>{ //When the time we specified earlier is over
        //Do stuff
         })
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id // to ensure same author is responding

 message.channel.send(embedMessage).then(() =>{
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { // after he sends a message to the same channel

// You can also use ".awaitReactions"   if you want to wait for reactions on the message sent
          

          max: 1,// maximum responses
          time: 30000,// timeout for waiting
          errors: ['time']// type of error
        })
    .then(message =>{
        // do what everyou like with the response
  
    })
    .catch(error => console.log)
});
```

Comment: I know how to make an embed. But im unsure how to edit the embed once its been sent to a channel. I need to edit a field within the embed once someone has reacted to it.

Comment: there is also  .awaitReactions